# Chrome in gnome to consume only available space?

Tags: fedora, gnome

`System-left` or `System-Right` binds the window to half screen size on the left or right side of the screen canvas.

Assuming I have only 30% open on the right side how to make it consume only 30% of screen canvas instead of 50%? Is it even possible in Gnome?

I'm using Fedora 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will largely depend on the version of Gnome that you're running:

In Gnome2, **compiz** is the way to go (with the grid plugin). For example, if you press `ctrl`+`alt`+`numkey-left` the active window will occupy the left 50% of your screen. If pressed again, it will ocupy 2/3 of your screen. And if pressed a third time, it will occupy 1/3 of your screen.

Apparently [compiz isn't compatible with Gnome3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112679/enabling-compiz-effects-on-gnome3) though, so you'd have to stick with whatever shell extensions can replicate.
I haven't tried any of these yet, but here goes:

- [gnome-shell-grid](https://github.com/paulswartz/gnome-shell-grid) extension - Apparently tries to mimic the behavior from compiz, but I find no mention of it handling screen thirds (only halves are mentioned).
- [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) extension - Seems very customizable.
- [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) extension - Apparently very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the default Shell. It would certainly be possible with a [Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/), but as far as I know, there is no current extension which does this.